# Get call stack in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I was wondering if I can get the caller of the method that caused an exception in .Net Core

For example:

There is a method called `CallerMethod()` in the Main Window  `Window_Loaded` event which calls another method in which I'm catching the exception.

I need to get `CallerMethod` name without all the `Environment.StackTrace` information. Furthermore, `exception.StackTrace`  only shows the method that throws the exception and not the call stack

I hope that I've properly explained the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43609326/stackframe-does-not-get-all-of-frames

Comment: Note that the stack trace is affected by compiler optimizations in release build, so it may not always be what you think it is.

Comment: @DanielA.White Thank you for the link

Comment: @Alejandro your note is very useful. The thing is that I can read CallerMethod name in the stack trace, but is there a way to only get its information for logging purposes and not the entire StackTrace?

Comment: Without a stacktrace: [CallerMemberNameAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing thank you this is helpful. I was able to get the the DoProcessing name using the attribute. But, my question is can I get the method's path/name in which I used the DoProcessing metthod?

Comment: You can only go one level up, but if you are interested in callers of DoProcessing, why not add the attribute there?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I wasn't fully aware of this, thanks. So, a solution would be to add the attribute to all the methods resembling DoProcessing in my application.